# Is there any method to sum elements in JAVA?

Tags: java, sum

Is there any equivalent of python's `sum()` in Java?

Comment: There's no such method in jdk, but you can implement one. Very simple, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into the language. There are plenty of libraries that do things like that, though. Or write your own three-line routine. How you do it depends on how you are representing your elements (the usual suspects—for double values—being `List<Double>` or `double[]`).

Answer (score 1):

No. Simply use a loop, to cycle through each element and generate a running total.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function like `sum()` in Java.
You may create a function by yourself. Something like this:

```
    public <T> T countArray(T[] array)
    {
        T tSum = 0;

        for (T t : array)
        {
            tSum += t;
        }

        return tSum;
    }

    public <T> T countCollection(Collection<T> coll)
    {
        T[] array = (T[])coll.ToArray(new T[0]);
        return countArray(array);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StatUtils.sum(double[])](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/StatUtils.html#sum%28double%5B%5D%29) from [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) library.
The advantage is that StatUtils has other useful functions and Commons Math has many other utils.